# How should we understand the value of a recent theory published on Phys. Rev. D?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gravity, particle-physics, gauge-theory

I would like to know what to make of this paper, published on *Phys. Rev. D* on the 11$^{th}$ of January:

> Quantum field theory of gravity with spin and scaling gauge invariance and spacetime dynamics with quantum inflation. Yue-Liang Wu. [*Phys. Rev. D* **93**, 024012 (2016)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.93.024012), [arXiv:1506.01807](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01807).

Does this theory unify gravity with quantum theory? I am a newbie to modern physics. Thanks!

Comment: Asking us for evaluation of a paper is off-topic. Please ask a more specific physics question, and show some research effort.

Comment: There is a different community, called physics overflow, where you can ask for a paper to be reviewed. In my (not so accurate) knowledge, it is not very active as of late, but maybe you can try there...

Comment: For a question this broad, [Physics Forums](http://www.physicsforums.com) is probably a better place. I have my reasons for not pointing people to Physics Overflow.

Comment: @David Z : would you care to elaborate?

Comment: People who vote for reopening should state if they have an answer to give, i.e. a small review. I would support that request then.

Comment: I tried skimming the paper, and it is not clear whether the standard model comes out at the same time. There is no claim of "unified theory". There is a claim that General Relativity is emergent for low energies. Still, even a consistent quantization of gravity should have made a stir  the past few months, since it appeared on arxiv. last June.

Comment: Perhaps it would be a valid question to ask about this claim : the gravity is a **basic force of spin gauge interaction locally** and an emergent GR otherwise. And by the way how comes the second (9) equality.